# Sonata User - Role security Access denied

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using SonataUserBundle and I'm trying to give LIST/EDIT access to some users.

**config.yml**

```yamel
#...
sonata_admin:
    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role
#...
```

I can see the roles `ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_*` listed in admin.

**security.yml**

```yamel
security:
    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous
    #...
    role_hierarchy:
        #...
        ROLE_EDIT_USER:
            - ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_LIST
            - ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_EDIT
        #...
```

But `ROLE_EDIT_USER` doesn't give access to User Admin.

I have no firewall rule for sonata.
If I use the handler `sonata.admin.security.handler.noop` I'm getting access, which proves (I think) that the access is actually denied by sonata.

What can deny me access to `ROLE_EDIT_USER` ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I didn't see I had also `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_*` listed in admin, I don't understand why.

So I had to set

```
    ROLE_EDIT_USER:
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_LIST
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_USER_EDIT
```

instead

Sometimes Symfony seems to me so complicated for simple things...

I spend 10x less time configuring same things with Django for example.
*Even if that is more related to Sonata than Symfony*